# comply with CAN-SPAM in workflow messages

Tags: email, message-templates, spam

I am using CiviCRM 5.18.4 with WordPress 5.3.2, and residing in the United States, where we are required by law to include certain info (our postal address and an opt-out link) in ALL our emails.  I can do this in my individual messages and bulk email footers, fine.  But they don't show up in any of the Mailflow messages.

I have tried adding

```
{$domain.address}
<p>To comply with CAN-SPAM laws, we remind you that you can also opt-out of all mailings from us.  To do so, <a href="{$action.optOutUrl}" click here</a>, or send mail to {$action.optOut}. </p>
```

near the bottom of the (html) message template, but it doesn't plug in the token values (or it just generates a critical error).

But even if I could get it to work, why am I figuring out how to tweak this?  Doesn't almost EVERYONE need to include a footer like this in almost ALL their workflow emails?

Comment: Is the above the EXACT text in your template? You're missing a `>` just before the "click here" words.

Answer (score 2):

Take out the $ signs. Smarty variables use $ signs, tokens don't. It is a little bit awkward when they're mixed in the same template.

I don't know the legal answer to the other part of the question, but bulk mailings include it by default.

Comment: Actually when I originally did it without the $, then when I submitted a donation I got:
<<
There has been a critical error on your website.
Learn more about debugging in WordPress.
>>
Any other suggestions, maybe about where in the template to put it, or how to format it correctly?

Comment: I just tried `{domain.address}` in the offline contribution receipt template and it worked, so maybe something else going on on that site? For testing purposes I put it at the bottom just before the `<body>` tag.

Comment: The missing > was caught early, but it took a lot more fiddling, especially with the placement of the token, to get it working.  Thanks very much for helping me test and troubleshoot!